# make Boostrap parent col collapse before child col?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im learning boostrap and stuck as this point :

- I created 1 row with 2 col
- 2'nd col contain 1 row with 2 col
- now when the viewport get smaller, the 2 child cols collapse before the 2 parent cols does
- So what i want is the parent cols to collapse first, before the 2 cols inside 2'nd col collapse
- Could someone tell me what to do ?

Below is the code example

```html
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid blue; min-height: 100px;max-width: 80%;">
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid black;min-height: 100px;">
            <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); min-height: 100px;">
                <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid rgb(9, 255, 0);min-height: 100px;">aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa</div>
                <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 221);min-height: 100px;">bbbbb  bbbb bbbb bbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbb</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 238, 0);min-height: 100px;">ccccc ccccccccccc  ccccccc  cccccc cccccc cccccc</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your griding system! like `md, lg, xl ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid blue; min-height: 100px;max-width: 80%;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid black;min-height: 100px;">Column 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 238, 0);min-height: 100px;">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid rgb(9, 255, 0);min-height: 100px;">Column 2 child 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 221);min-height: 100px;">Column 2 child 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```